# Python 2.7 Multiprocessing on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing, but I need to parse a large number of xml files, the parsing is part of a larger application. Parsing can happen in the "background" so it doesn't affect the main application. To that end I have the following (exerpt)

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO
import multiprocessing as mp


def parseBookXML(xmlFile):

    f = open(xmlFile)
    xml = f.read()
    f.close()

    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))

    #now write it out to file
    with open("out_filename", "w") as fout:
    fout.write(ET.tostring(tree))

def do_process_file():
     process = mp.Process(target=parseBookXML, args=(c:\my_xml_file.xml))
     process.start()
```

Essentially I want to call the parseBookXML function, pass it a file as a parameter (or even a list of xml files) and let the parsing happen it its own process and complete.

When doing this normally (i.e without process.start()) it works fine.

```
def do_process_file():
     self.parseBookXML(c:\my_xml_file.xml)
```

The above works fine, the xml_file is parsed no errors.

But making use of the do_process_file function gives me errors, along the lines of

> AttributeError no module etree

I am on Windows using python 2.7, not using the REPL or interactive interpreter. I have read that windows differs from linux,

I have read a little about mulitprocessing not pickling in Windows (i'm not sure what that means)

what I really need to know is how to make this kind of function work.

Comment: Multiprocessing may not help you as much as you think here... Unless your XML files are on different volumes, you're probably more likely to thrash the disk then get any considerable performance gains. Multithreading/processing is better suited to application with network usage or distributable cpu loads...

Comment: @Shadow - not necessarily, if those XML files are huge and complex, XML parsing can eat a sizeable chunk of CPU time guaranteeing at least some speed-up (assuming multicore/multiprocessor environment, of course).

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace. I don't see any cause for an attribute error here... Also the filename you are passing it is not a string...

Answer (score 0):

`from lxml import etree` seems like your python does not have module `lxml` in it. Some module are different based on OS. Please check whether module `lxml` is available for windows or not.

Comment: lxml works fine on Windows. I have sucessuflly parsed many files using in in my setup. However when I introduce the multiprocessing part, I get the error

Comment: Can you try this in Linux or Unix first and check. It clearly Library/Module issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Linux or Unix, I only have Windows. Thanks